# Citation warnings - Citation 'bibtexkey' on page 7 undefined.

Tags: bibtex, warnings

Hey so I am having issues with my citations.  I am getting multiple warnings for a number of my citations saying: Citation `Bibtexkey' on page 6 undefined.  Some of my citations are fine while others will not work and show up as ( ?) in the pdf.  There is nothing wrong with my bibtex file within JabRef that I can see, so I do not no what is causing this to happen.

I am using TeXStudio.  Here is a MWE.  nuthesis is a class designed for my universities graduate students.  I don't believe it has anything to do with the issue as I know many many people who have used this document class successfully.  I've tried using different styles as well but no luck.  I have a lot of other packages involved, but not sure if they may be affecting the bib.  I've seen people talk about how you compile matters, but I'm not sure what is meant by this.

```
\documentclass[print,double]{nuthesis}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[
  unicode=true,
  urlcolor = blue,
  colorlinks = true,
  citecolor = blue,
  linkcolor = blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\cite{Mero} 
\cite{Schaffer}
\cite{Keldysh}

\end{document}

\bibliography{Thesis_BIB}
\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid that is nowhere near enough information to go on. How are those bib entries defined?! Note that a Minimal Working Example should *compile* to demonstrate the issue. I can't compile your code so I can't reproduce the issue...

Comment: Are you running bibtex between each compile?

Comment: Please add Mero, Schaffer, and Keldysh with help of the package `filecontents`, put your bibliography commands in front of `\end{documentclass}` and have a look, if your error consists with `article` as well. If it does, replace `nuthesis` in your question with `article`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried just about every suggested answer I could find throughout the exchange and couldn't get anything to work.  Turns out, there was a fault in my .bib file, but it was something I would have never known was not allowed until I created a new file and one by one entered in the bib entries.

What I found is that TeXStudio does not allow book references with both an author and an editor.  This did not pop up as an error or warning explicitly in TeXStudio, but instead I found this by going to Tools -> Bibliography.

This is annoying for a relatively new user to TeXStudio and especially JabRef since JabRef lists both author and editor as "required fields" when creating a book entry.  But all is well that ends well!  I will have my thesis done on time woo!! Thanks again to all that tried to help!  I am sorry for failing to provide enough information to create a MWE, but it turns out that may have just wasted time for you guys anyways.  Thanks again, chris

Comment: No. An MWE would not have wasted others' time because you would have discovered the problem in creating it. (It isn't an MWE unless you can reproduce the error with it...) So creating one would probably have resulted in your not posting at all or posting a different question people stood a chance of answering. Note that I'm not saying this to be critical but just to explain why people keep asking for MWEs and why *all* questions should include one.

Comment: I very much doubt that TeXStudio 'does not allow book references with both an author and an editor'. TeXStudio is *just* a front-end. It has nothing to do with the acceptability or otherwise of your code. Since `@book` generally allows both author and editor (though it doesn't require it - very odd if JabRef insists on both), either this is some peculiarity of `nuthesis` or of `aipnum4-1` or that is not really the cause of the problem.

Comment: @cfr I understand.  I'll be sure to create MWE's and test them from now on before I post.  JabRef lets you insert just one, but they are both listed under the required field tab so I thought I needed to have both there.. The reason I thought it had something to do with TeXStudio is because that is where I got the message.  I did try one other bib style and got the same result, but didn't try another document, I didn't think it had anything to do with the bibliography.

Comment: You can test by compiling your document at the command line (recommended for debugging). That will show you for sure whether TeXStudio is involved. If it is, that would be rather serious - your frontend ought not to interfere with compilation in that way. It is *just* a fancy editor... It shows you the errors produced by the underlying commands when you compile. It is *just* the messenger...