# Citation warnings - Citation 'bibtexkey' on page '_' undefined

Tags: bibtex, citing, warnings

Hey I am still having issues with my citations.  It is the very last thing I need to do before my thesis is complete, but I have to turn in in by Thursday!

I am getting multiple warnings for a number of my citations saying: Citation `Bibtexkey' on page '6' undefined. Some of my citations are fine while others will not work and show up as ( ?) in the pdf. There is nothing wrong with my bibtex file within JabRef that I can see, so I do not no what is causing this to happen.

I am using TeXStudio. Here is a MWE. nuthesis is a class designed for my universities graduate students. I don't believe it has anything to do with the issue as I know many many people who have used this document class successfully. I've tried using different styles as well but no luck. I have a lot of other packages involved, but not sure if they may be affecting the bib. I've seen people talk about how you compile matters, i.e. latex bibtex latex latex, which I believe I am doing correctly but I still get errors.

```
    \documentclass[print,double]{nuthesis}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage[
      unicode=true,
      urlcolor = blue,
      colorlinks = true,
      citecolor = blue,
      linkcolor = blue]{hyperref}

    \begin{document}

    \citep{MeroLiu} 
    \citep{Bonse}
    \citep{Keldysh}

    \bibliography{Thesis_BIB}
    \bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}

\end{document}
```

MeroLiu and Bonse are examples of two citations that give warnings.  Keldysh is my most cited reference and cites correctly throughout my entire thesis.

Here are the bibtex sources:

```
@ARTICLE{Keldysh,
  author = {L. V. Keldysh},
  title = {Ionization in the field of a strong electromagnetic wave},
  journal = {Soviet Physics Jetp},
  year = {1965},
  volume = {20},
  pages = {1307-1314},
  owner = {Chris Ferris},
  timestamp = {2014.02.18}
}
@ARTICLE{MeroLiu,
  author = {M. Mero and J. Liu and W. Rudolph and D. Ristau and K. Starke},
  title = {Scaling laws of femtosecond laser pulse induced breakdown in oxide
    films},
  journal = {Physical Review B},
  year = {2005},
  volume = {71},
  pages = {1-7},
  owner = {Chris Ferris},
  timestamp = {2014.02.18}
}
@ARTICLE{Bonse,
  author = {J. Bonse and J. M. Wrobel and J. Kruger and W. Kautek},
  title = {Ultrashort-pulse laser ablation of indium phosphide in air},
  journal = {Applied Physics A},
  year = {2001},
  volume = {72},
  pages = {89-94},
  owner = {Chris Ferris},
  timestamp = {2014.04.07}
}
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Nothing gets read past `\end{document}`, so I hope that's not really how your thesis file is structured!  Also: we probably need access to `nuthesis.cls`.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. You can add additional information to your other question (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169673/39222). Also, if you really need this done by Thursday, I suggest you take another look at the comments there as they should help you to produce a Minimal Working Example or, failing that, at least point up `nuthesis` as the culprit. You are not giving people code they can reproduce the problem with. That can only mean you are not in that much of a hurry to find a solution...

Comment: These bib entries are fine.  There are several likely culprits: (1) the code from your real thesis, which you must(!) provide here in the form of a MWE; (2) `nuthesis` is faulty: thesis classes are often (critically) dependent on specific (and eventually outdated) versions of other packages; (3) other bib entries are faulty, which are causing the problems you're experiencing with this one (e.g., a missing closing brace of $); (4) ....  Note that the example file you have provided is untestable, but if you switch to any other viable document class (e.g., `report`), everything words fine.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input!  I ended up going through entry by entry until I finally got texstudio to tell me something about one of my entries.  Apparently it doesn't like both an author and editor for a book entry yet JabRef has these both as "required fields".  @cfr I'm sorry for repeating my question, I felt it'd be easier to start over than update an old thread.  I will keep from doing this in the future.  Thanks again for the help!